# Generic Swift Function Error Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, generics

```
func multiply<T: Strideable> (lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T {
    return lhs * rhs
}
```

Why is this returning an error of:
No '*' candidates produce the expected contextual result result type 'T'

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around by extending the * operator to the Double, Int, and Float types.

```
protocol Numeric {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double: Numeric {}
extension Float: Numeric {}
extension Int: Numeric {}
```

Comment: Nice experimenting, but I wonder what the downsides of extending all those primitive types with a protocol that overloads the multiplication symbol is, if any?

Comment: This is fine, and the multiplication operator isn't being overloaded, it's just letting functions that take a Numeric type that that operator is available to use

Answer (score 0):

Look into Strideable protocol, it does not have method '*'. If you rather want it so that 'T' can be multiplied to another 'T', you should rather declare it in such a way that 'T' has '*'.

```
func multiply<T: Strideable> (lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T where T:IntegerArithmetic  {
    return lhs * rhs
}
```

Or, you can also do as other answer suggests, since with this method you can only use Integers.